# How to fix a hash error

Tags: apt, updates

I type : `sudo apt-get update` in terminal and everything is okay exept that one :

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/dc4a2e2feb00361be7fb132b8b6642ebc1093babafe52e66733f04bf84eda153  Somme de contrôle de hachage incohérente
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:557796 [weak]
    - SHA256:dc4a2e2feb00361be7fb132b8b6642ebc1093babafe52e66733f04bf84eda153
    - SHA1:3b156054f17a03eed4661ecc0c7ab074b055f9fa [weak]
    - MD5Sum:d4ac6cf132136b89d0b4cf56bc50f440 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:98b6f3654825dd68b48023147c3a8f4f9c73f6ae2125cf07eddcef250e315524
    - SHA1:9abe37bf51c4d4506a2b365092b19dd7727ab623 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:283fd9cb18a9d20e27c57d3baeb41492 [weak]
    - Filesize:557796 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Mon, 25 Mar 2019 12:55:55 +0000
   Release file created at: Mon, 25 Mar 2019 12:55:32 +0000
```

Answer (score 4):

It is an error with the hashsum. apt-get is geting a list with all hashes. If the hash in the list differs from the hash of the downloaded file, it won't be installed. That is very clever behavior.
Most common for this issue are broken proxys or internet related filter.

If it was just a hickup, try `sudo apt-get clean`, which will clear `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` and than try `sudo apt-get update`, again.
If this won't work, check your connection, if there is any device or service that is messing up with your connection.

Comment: Thank you ! It’s works too. But I also change my server and the it’s done

Answer (score 0):

In my case, switching from France server to principal server just solved the problem.

Translating from the names in French, I opened Software & Updates (Logiciels et mises à jour) and switched server in the select box *Download from:* (Télécharger depuis). You can open it from the "Activities" view or from a shell with `software-properties-gtk`.