# what can be causes of errors in apt hashes, down to details?

Tags: apt, upgrade, hash

I've got in my GUI notification, that new APT updates are ready.

When I have run `apt upgrade`, I got several error messages, similar to described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128594/how-to-fix-a-hash-error). However difference is that hash errors were detected during download. Only one repository source seem to be cause of errors, all others were Ok. I followed [recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128603/1593967) from same source to do `apt clear`,`apt update` and `apt upgrade` -- and it cleared up, so my questions are:

1. is that normal that one repo source breaks and rest are Ok?
2. what could be the cause? files on source updated but hash files not? or is it my side?
3. if clear up doesn't help, what it means?

Snippet of actual errors posted from 2nd attempt below:

```
aytvill@dendrarium:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-159 linux-headers-5.4.0-159-generic linux-image-5.4.0-159-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-159-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-159-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  code docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin gh google-cloud-sdk google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python google-cloud-sdk-cloud-build-local libsmbclient libsox-fmt-alsa
  libsox-fmt-base libsox3 libwbclient0 mokutil python3-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs signal-desktop smbclient sox terraform
24 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 470 MB/470 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,293 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-samba amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [2,671 kB]
Get:2 https://cli.github.com/packages stable/main amd64 gh amd64 2.34.0 [11.2 MB]                                                                                                                            
Get:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-cli amd64 5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [13.3 MB]                                                                                
Get:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main amd64 google-cloud-sdk all 445.0.0-0 [153 MB]                                                                                                     
Get:5 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal/main amd64 terraform amd64 1.5.7-1 [21.8 MB]                                                                                                                  
Get:6 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial/main amd64 signal-desktop amd64 6.30.1 [113 MB]                                                                                                          
Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 code amd64 1.82.0-1694039253 [95.6 MB]                                                                                                     
Get:8 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 samba-common-bin amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [575 kB]                                                                           
Get:9 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 smbclient amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [414 kB]                                                                                  
Get:10 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 samba-common all 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [73.0 kB]                                                                               
Get:11 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 samba-dsdb-modules amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [283 kB]                                                                        
Get:12 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsmbclient amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [59.6 kB]                                                                             
Get:13 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libwbclient0 amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [211 kB]                                                                              
Get:14 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.5 [5,631 kB]                                                                              
Err:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-cli amd64 5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal                                                                                          
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:48a28706597c9c94de2903eec223b8cdb85fa5997817bb371ec868c180762278a1970467a0f8af596a08d6a66d97d56264d552e460a98b6b6c6fea9a26d9a30e
   - SHA256:37373a59399961686da76925925d6e7f68439f282cdb936636a2c87470f3be7f
   - SHA1:c8394498414759d7e39daaa92553af2b66aef671 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:01f7adc430f866510607cb4dab8563fb [weak]
   - Filesize:13281938 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:f491461c67e20ada0c594cf98a81f9e15c2175d0e091697a59751f9d49bc68d3c73bd0cd988c94fb4e1082c983d0809f90b314d14cff3f43383d02e72ab78d5a
   - SHA256:50273b1bd00bb8c6cd632ec35a3f24c531f3f88c938622f5d8f560ad7c470b5b
   - SHA1:02f3e32a0104889b5ce2a2f37af7375babd14576 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5cfccb2875121e0a176a8c35388ec6b9 [weak]
   - Filesize:13281938 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:03 +0000
Get:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [22.6 MB]                                                                                   
Err:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal                                                                                             
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:c531d0b39ac7adda4606bee84b14ac922d99e2faa351c40aeb9d57aacd047213e721c54c2c3c05a95d7d33f20451c0c7ebb2208356a33ec4628a08631d96406c
   - SHA256:078fa6be2c76c61bc53d4c04b3f8794c29dd27da13cfa471395a6999986df21c
   - SHA1:fb4914a16643d029de5f98e4770c92a49af76d4b [weak]
   - MD5Sum:c0eae530ec6b8bc96ec5006800c192d0 [weak]
   - Filesize:22594406 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:bfab4390fe61b8af372d2fb88ff5343407de4a857ea26e5b25266fad3d1c13a4fd39f5bb47dc134d78d1161aace92b4c9e70a083b247e82b1a214ce27dc37556
   - SHA256:6ef661f741780de72785e20d0420abe219a1641631eeaa498fe8befa0e0451ec
   - SHA1:642de6ed6d4ab58bc3ca0f312947d903cdf71e8f [weak]
   - MD5Sum:bbd38911923ac2487da5a1024498c15c [weak]
   - Filesize:22594406 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:04 +0000
Get:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-rootless-extras amd64 5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [9,038 kB]                                                                  
Err:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-rootless-extras amd64 5:24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal                                                                             
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:cd75b801a9dca90e28a8fe17a00ee85c9d2531e8ff97da9f4eaab64de84c0705a36f1714412cd812897c02fba1c05cadf25332f5ec0d98cd7276206063b50cf5
   - SHA256:0916c2be3705104be9712fe0f00c916d74fee748fba3ce38b47c8dfeb6fb86fe
   - SHA1:2916e916d7e5b8d23a9fa25242f9c2c7ebeafeef [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f33df4e0a90342aaaf63b6504f692cf8 [weak]
   - Filesize:9037876 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:eefbd1db94ef5a668a26f1d743e5943e9099aa9545d8deacbd34b870a1e48be6a2f1302405225d5c88e8578167a3753cb7dd70a4d7b1c4480b4937ed84b947d3
   - SHA256:5f02da7a08735173003aa44cabeac5f15471eb99174180251d58b5633fccfccb
   - SHA1:075a067e63963162d6f077dbc784cb718293f961 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:515f4a055b2a27ea696538bc017be580 [weak]
   - Filesize:9037876 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:03 +0000
Get:17 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-compose-plugin amd64 2.21.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal [11.9 MB]                                                                         
Err:17 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-compose-plugin amd64 2.21.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal                                                                                   
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA512:2507e1fb3a2c70c9964b921c9ccbd6c2592ec041ceb52f9df732565cc531d94279e5a2dbc12c3f788605368382c524bfb995f0cfb75ea07f84f8b3a18b6a3592
   - SHA256:d43f0ac8929bc715c3664b639d2b6458d7b0857b0a4d1e67b51cdbbee74d62ad
   - SHA1:7e7d494c02359532ac19c9ed007c4b871e2e617e [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f3ce53187095ce43cb65ffc7f229e92c [weak]
   - Filesize:11931062 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA512:fc49fe287eaea291b7dc9216bf4d049d6afcf1c67f201341176b28b26b5d27fb72a9095213c96a687cfbdbd3a63d597624e427bcda603377024b59f8415b308b
   - SHA256:afee28f01d858b5d052d3d2b3efbdb84306bb3bd85f1529cc6d087930475db0c
   - SHA1:766497ea5a59c3f0c120486cefe7e153187b8353 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f9d40de85c31a3b1aebf5d631008b3d3 [weak]
   - Filesize:11931062 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:05 +0000
Get:18 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main amd64 google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python all 445.0.0-0 [5,942 kB]                                                                                
Get:19 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main amd64 google-cloud-sdk-cloud-build-local amd64 445.0.0-0 [2,719 kB]                                                                              
Fetched 470 MB in 1min 38s (4,779 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                      
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:48a28706597c9c94de2903eec223b8cdb85fa5997817bb371ec868c180762278a1970467a0f8af596a08d6a66d97d56264d552e460a98b6b6c6fea9a26d9a30e
    - SHA256:37373a59399961686da76925925d6e7f68439f282cdb936636a2c87470f3be7f
    - SHA1:c8394498414759d7e39daaa92553af2b66aef671 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:01f7adc430f866510607cb4dab8563fb [weak]
    - Filesize:13281938 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:f491461c67e20ada0c594cf98a81f9e15c2175d0e091697a59751f9d49bc68d3c73bd0cd988c94fb4e1082c983d0809f90b314d14cff3f43383d02e72ab78d5a
    - SHA256:50273b1bd00bb8c6cd632ec35a3f24c531f3f88c938622f5d8f560ad7c470b5b
    - SHA1:02f3e32a0104889b5ce2a2f37af7375babd14576 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:5cfccb2875121e0a176a8c35388ec6b9 [weak]
    - Filesize:13281938 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:03 +0000
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:c531d0b39ac7adda4606bee84b14ac922d99e2faa351c40aeb9d57aacd047213e721c54c2c3c05a95d7d33f20451c0c7ebb2208356a33ec4628a08631d96406c
    - SHA256:078fa6be2c76c61bc53d4c04b3f8794c29dd27da13cfa471395a6999986df21c
    - SHA1:fb4914a16643d029de5f98e4770c92a49af76d4b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:c0eae530ec6b8bc96ec5006800c192d0 [weak]
    - Filesize:22594406 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:bfab4390fe61b8af372d2fb88ff5343407de4a857ea26e5b25266fad3d1c13a4fd39f5bb47dc134d78d1161aace92b4c9e70a083b247e82b1a214ce27dc37556
    - SHA256:6ef661f741780de72785e20d0420abe219a1641631eeaa498fe8befa0e0451ec
    - SHA1:642de6ed6d4ab58bc3ca0f312947d903cdf71e8f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:bbd38911923ac2487da5a1024498c15c [weak]
    - Filesize:22594406 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:04 +0000
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-rootless-extras_24.0.6-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:cd75b801a9dca90e28a8fe17a00ee85c9d2531e8ff97da9f4eaab64de84c0705a36f1714412cd812897c02fba1c05cadf25332f5ec0d98cd7276206063b50cf5
    - SHA256:0916c2be3705104be9712fe0f00c916d74fee748fba3ce38b47c8dfeb6fb86fe
    - SHA1:2916e916d7e5b8d23a9fa25242f9c2c7ebeafeef [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f33df4e0a90342aaaf63b6504f692cf8 [weak]
    - Filesize:9037876 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:eefbd1db94ef5a668a26f1d743e5943e9099aa9545d8deacbd34b870a1e48be6a2f1302405225d5c88e8578167a3753cb7dd70a4d7b1c4480b4937ed84b947d3
    - SHA256:5f02da7a08735173003aa44cabeac5f15471eb99174180251d58b5633fccfccb
    - SHA1:075a067e63963162d6f077dbc784cb718293f961 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:515f4a055b2a27ea696538bc017be580 [weak]
    - Filesize:9037876 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:03 +0000
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-compose-plugin_2.21.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA512:2507e1fb3a2c70c9964b921c9ccbd6c2592ec041ceb52f9df732565cc531d94279e5a2dbc12c3f788605368382c524bfb995f0cfb75ea07f84f8b3a18b6a3592
    - SHA256:d43f0ac8929bc715c3664b639d2b6458d7b0857b0a4d1e67b51cdbbee74d62ad
    - SHA1:7e7d494c02359532ac19c9ed007c4b871e2e617e [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f3ce53187095ce43cb65ffc7f229e92c [weak]
    - Filesize:11931062 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA512:fc49fe287eaea291b7dc9216bf4d049d6afcf1c67f201341176b28b26b5d27fb72a9095213c96a687cfbdbd3a63d597624e427bcda603377024b59f8415b308b
    - SHA256:afee28f01d858b5d052d3d2b3efbdb84306bb3bd85f1529cc6d087930475db0c
    - SHA1:766497ea5a59c3f0c120486cefe7e153187b8353 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f9d40de85c31a3b1aebf5d631008b3d3 [weak]
    - Filesize:11931062 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 08 Sep 2023 19:21:05 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste text of error messages into your question, and formatting it as code, without the antispam alarms going off. As it is, your question can only be answered generally. It very occasionally happens that a hash error occurs. It can be a network issue, or files can be out of sync, either because of ongoing maintenance or human error. Redownloading the files concerned will then resolve the issue.

Comment: 1) It's not normal that **any** repo source breaks. 2) The cause requires troubleshooting. Common, easy causes were fixed 20 years ago. 3) Not an understandable question. Perhaps a translation error?

Comment: @jos guess what... I had it wrapped as code, but StackExchange insisted it's spam. Also some meta-SE advised to remove it. Once I removed it, I was able to post. I'm puzzled what to do about it... I kept it as ASCII text just in case, but I doubt SE will let me it now as edited piece

Comment: Post it on https://pastebin.com/ and put a link here.

Comment: @Jos well, this time it flew under radar somehow as added in edit, so we have it up there as code block